# Full page-width div

Tags: html, css

I have a div (as the 'headline' for a test-site), but i always get a small margin left and right, even with my width set to 100%.

CSS:

```
.humpty {
   background-color: pink;
   text-align: center;
   font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
   color: gray;
   font-size: 30px;
   font-weight: lighter;
   width: 100%;*/
   padding-top: 1px;
   padding-bottom: 1px;
   margin: 0 -9999rem;
   padding: 0.25rem 9999rem;
}
```

html:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
      <title>Test Site</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="humpty">
            Main Title for this Page entirely
      </div>
```

Comment: Mostly it is because the body padding, try adding this to your css `body{padding:0;margin:0}`

Answer (score 2):

add

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
}
```